# Mounting an ext3 filesystem with user privileges

Tags: mount, users, ext3

I'm trying to mount an ext3 file system from another Linux installation so that the user, not root, will have full access to all the files. (I really do need user to have access to those files, because I would like to use them from another computer via sshfs, and sshfs will only give the user's access rights to the files.)

If I run `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/whatever` all files are only accessible by root.

I've also tried `mount -o nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda1 /mnt/whatever` as instructed by [a SuperUser question discussing ext4](https://superuser.com/questions/196653/how-do-i-manually-mount-a-linux-file-system-read-write-as-a-normal-user/196678#196678) but that fails with an error, and `dmesg` reports:

`EXT3-fs: Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value`

How can I mount the filesystem?

Comment: I'd say that [Gilles' answer](http://superuser.com/questions/196653/how-do-i-manually-mount-a-linux-file-system-read-write-as-a-normal-user/196684#196684) in the SuperUser question you mentioned is the correct one.  Indeed, then [man page mount(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) does not list `uid=...` and `gid=...` options for none of the ext2/3/4 filesystems.

Comment: @Riccardo Thanks, that was the correct solution! First mounting the ext into some directory regularly, then mounting that directory with `bindfs -u $(id -u) -g $(id -g)` into the final destination. Write it up as an answer, maybe?

Comment: Since the answer is [Gilles'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) and he's very active on this forum as well, I'll leave it up to him to re-post it here and collect the deserved credit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On an ext4 filesystem (like ext2, ext3, and most other Unix-originating filesystems), the effective file permissions don't depend on who mounted the filesystem or on mount options, only on the metadata stored within the filesystem.

If you have a removable filesystem that uses different user IDs from your system, you can use [`bindfs`](https://bindfs.org/) to provide a view of any filesystem with different ownership or permissions. The removable filesystem must be mounted already, e.g. on `/mnt/sda1`; then, if you want a particular user to appear as the owner of all files, you can run something like

```
mkdir /home/$user/sda1
bindfs --no-allow-other -u $user -g $group /mnt/sda1 /home/$user/sda1
```

Comment: Thank you from me as well! With a little tweak, this also works for devices like e. g. hot-plugged SATA DVD-ROMs (which was the device I had problems with). HOWEVER, the device will always be mounted `000` for some reason (d---------) so you have to specify `-p 700` to the `bindfs` line to access the files on the DVD via `dolphin`/`nautilus` etc., for instance.

Comment: Would be nice if `bindfs` could accept dictionaries for translating any set of UIDs and GIDs...

Comment: I had to use the `--no-allow-other` option too. This stops `bindfs` from asking for permissions that my OS (Ubuntu 22.04) doesn't grant by default.