# How to make a partition that separated from OS?

Tags: mount, partition, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in `/dev/sda1` and Fedora 25 in `/dev/sda3`. I want to create a partition to store my downloaded file(i.e. application, source code, book etc.).

Currently, I store the file in the current partition of the working OS and to access the file from another OS just mount the partition.

This solution works. But, I want to a separate partition for only this purpose and neither OS owns it, to access the file contained the partition every OS have to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** You just need to create another partition, and make a filesystem on it. Then add it to `/etc/fstab` on both systems. Make sure your user IDs match. Add any bind mounts and/or symlinks you want for convenience.

**Details:**

First: this is much easier if your user ID numbers match on both distros. You can run `id` to check what your user ID number is. If they don't match, it'll be annoying (because there isn't a way to turn off permission checks on, e.g., ext4).

> - [Is it possible to disable file permissions on a ext3 or ext4 file-system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67105/is-it-possible-to-disable-file-permissions-on-a-ext3-or-ext4-file-system)
> - [External hard drive permissions - ext4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126213/external-hard-drive-permissions-ext4)

So if they don't match, you probably want to change one. The basic process is that you log out, log in as a different user, and use `sudo groupmod -g new-gid your-group` to change the group id and `sudo usermod -u new-uid your-user` to change your userid. At least on Debian, these are documented to also change ownership of your home directory and mail spool. You probably also want to do a `find / -uid old-user-id -or -gid old-group-id` to find any files or directories it missed and `chown your-user:your-group filename` to fix them. (I couldn't find a question to link to—so if you're at all unclear on this, please ask a second question, and link to this).

Second: You need a spare partition. Use your favorite partition table editor to create one. This presumes you have free space; if not, you'll have to shrink some existing partitions. I definitely recommend a backup before shrinking any partition. You'll probably have to reboot to activate the new partition table, go ahead and do so.

Third: format the new partition. E.g., `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdaX`.

Fourth: Create a directory where you want to mount it. You could put it in your home directory, but I think it'd actually be more useful to mount it somewhere else, then use bind mounts (for one thing, who wants a non-removable `lost+found` in his/her Documents folder?). You can put it wherever—hypothetically, let's say you mount it at `/shared`. You need to do this on both distros.

Add an entry to `/etc/fstab` on both distros. It should look something like this:

```fstab
# dev       mountdir  fs     options     dump pass
/dev/sdaX   /shared   ext4   defaults    0    2
```

Now, go ahead and mount it: `sudo mount /shared`. Create yourself a directory inside it (`sudo mkdir /shared/your-username; sudo chown your-username: /shared/your-username`).

You can now create subdirectories inside your directory (without sudo), and of course also files. You can also put symlinks from your home directory (on each distro)—e.g., if you've made a `/shared/your-user/Documents`, you could

```
# do these steps on each distro
mv Documents Documents.old
ln -s /shared/your-user/Documents Documents
mv -i Documents.old/* Documents/
rmdir Documents.old
```

An alternative is to use bind mounts, but I'd not bother with that unless you really need them (e.g., to make a single directory read-only, etc.)