# Mounting Ext3 in linux different user

Tags: mount, non-root-user, ext3

I am trying to mount an ext3 based memory stick in Linux based development board.

I used `mount` with `-u`  and `-g` for mounting the fat based memory stick with different user.

When I tried the same command for ext3, it failed.

I read in help that ext3 doesn't support `-g` and `-u`.

After reading about `bindfs`, I've built the bindfs for ARM and was able to mirror the already mounted ext3 fs with a different user.

Now the issue is the removal of the memory stick, which has to unbind and unmount the fs before removal. Otherwise the OS keeps showing that the ext3 fs is mounted and mirrored. It also hangs the system.

Unbinding and unmounting can be done as root only.

Is there any other way to mount ext3 without being root?

Using `chown` is not an option.

Comment: There are similar questions on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/34066/74792) and [Super User](http://superuser.com/q/519824/2357).

Comment: There's also a similar one here: ["External hard drive permissions - ext4"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126213/1174).