# gpt ext4 /etc/fstab doesn't work

Tags: mount, fstab

I have tried using 3 different identifiers to mount my partition at `/dev/sdb1` to `/mnt/drive2`, but every time I boot it doesn't seem to work and I have to mount it manually. I am connected remotely so I don't know console output during the boot process. It is a GPT drive and has only one partition of type `ext4`.

Here's my `/etc/fstab`:[image: Screenshot of /etc/fstab]

The last three lines are my attempts to mount the same partition with `PARTUUID`, `UUID`, and the `/dev/sdb1`  path. None of them worked.
Curiously enough, my `NTFS` partition mounts successfully.

I'm running Arch Linux.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: @roaima I'm sorry, I'm running Putty on Linux which doesn't allow me to copy-paste.

Comment: Sorry can't read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please do `mount -a` and if there is any error it will be printed to terminal.

Also by doing `dmesg | grep "sd[a-z]"` and `dmesg | grep "mount"` you can investigate mount errors during boot after booting your linux.

Comment: Thanks to you, I found the error! `gid` shows up as an unrecognized mount option. According to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14716), `ext` filesystems don't support options like `gid`. Thank you!